# How to upsert an expectation with an object callback

Tags: java, mockserver

I feel like I must be missing something obvious but can't seem to figure this one out.

For this project I am writing an http mock with [mock-server](https://www.mock-server.com/) using `upsert` so that during the runtime of mock I can change the behavior by upserting an expectation.

So like this:

```
mock.upsert(
  new Expectation(request().withMethod("GET").withPath(MY_PATH))
    .thenRespond(response().withBody(json("{\"hello\": \"world\"}")))
    .withId(MY_REQUEST_ID));
```

Now I need some more dynamic behavior so I want to use a callback.

```
mock.when(request().withMethod("POST").withPath(MY_PATH))
  .respond(
    httpRequest -> {
      final var response = dynamicResponse();
      return response().withBody(json(response));
     });
```

Now I can not figure out how to combine the above, so that I have an expectation with a known id, that I can upsert. `Expectation` does have an `thenRespond` overload that takes an [`HttpObjectCallback`](https://mock-server.com/versions/5.11.2/apidocs/org/mockserver/mock/Expectation.html#thenRespond-org.mockserver.model.HttpObjectCallback-) which sounds like what I am after, but that needs a clientId which I don't no where to get from, or how to pass the actual callback.

Again it feels like I am missing something obvious. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add .withId into the dynamic return line "return response().withBody(json(response))" assuming your question boils down to "I need to set an ID in the dynamic response". Hard to follow a bit of what you were expecting in your question.

Comment: No that is not supported. It indeed is what my question boils down to how to set an id on an expectation with a dynamic response. So that I can upsert the expectation later.